# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, summation, uniform-convergence

I'm struggling to find the radius of converge of the following sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}
\end{equation}
When I apply the Dalambre's criterion I get:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}}}{\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}}=1
\end{equation}
When I apply the other criterion:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(\frac{\frac{x^{n}}{1-x^{n}}}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}}}-1\right)=0
\end{equation}
And i have absolutely no idea how to proceed from here...

Comment: I would start by seeing where $\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$ converges to $0$

Comment: **d'Alembert**, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not a power series so here we don't talk about radius of convergence. $$R=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}}}{\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x\frac{1-x^n}{1-x^{n+1}}$$
If $|x|<1$
$$R=x$$ as $x^n$ goes to zero.

If $|x|>1$
$$R=1$$ The criterion does not decide but the general term of the serie does nor converge to zero, so it cannot be convergent.

For $|x|=1$ is not defined. So the values for $x$ such the series is convergent are $(-1,1) $

Answer (score 5):

Let me start by pointing out that the term "radius of convergence" is usually reserved for power series, and this is **not** a power series.

Now we investigate for which $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the series converges. We start by applying the divergence test. Now clearly $x\notin\{-1,1\}$ right of the bat, as we cannot have division by zero, and then for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^n}-1\right)=\begin{cases}
-1, &\lvert x \rvert >1, \\
0, &\lvert x \rvert <1,
\end{cases}$$

and so we know now immediately that if we have convergence, then we must have that $x\in(-1,1)$. We now investigate these $x$. Indeed we have that, if $\lvert x\rvert<1$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}}}{\frac{x^{n}}{1-x^{n}}} \right\rvert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{x(1-x^{n})}{1-x^{n+1}} \right\rvert=\lvert x \rvert <1.$$

It follows by the ratio test that the series converges for $x\in(-1,1)$. We can thus conclude that

- if $x\in\{-1,1\}$, the series is undefined,
- if $x\in(-1,1)$, the series converges,
- if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$, the series diverges.

We could thus say (although I disapprove of the terminology as we do not have a power series), that the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: As a generating function for the divisor function  it can be seen as a power series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  d(n)\, x^n$ - see [OEIS A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005)